# SWRevealViewController Pan gesture is not working when the from view is scrolling enabled

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, gesture, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a side menu which is impelemented by [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) and my frontView has a collection view.
SWReveal works fine by tap on menu button, but the pen gesture is not working on collection view (which has a horizontal scrolling enabled).
can any one help me to force collection view to accept the pen gesture of the SWReveal?

Answer (score 1):

SWRevealViewController's gesture controller and collection view are been clashing that's why the problem occurs. Other than that as per my view there is no practical way to identify what user wants to open by the gesture.

[image]

But Client needs a solution and the image shows it! keep user interaction ON of the view.

Let me know if you find anything else.

Best of luck.

Comment: Yes you are right, i have two ideas. First of all, get the touch position and if was so close to the left edge of the view, open the menu instead of scrolling the collection. Second of all. Open menu by gesture only in collection view first index, where there is no more left scrolling for collection view.

Answer (score 1):

Add below code in viewDidLoad

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
```